# Let's add the "status declined" tag, and let's use pink "status" tags more often

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, etiquetas

Let's use the pink "status-etc." tags within Meta more often.  Let's also create a "status-declined" tag for Meta.

Answer (score 1):

In Meta there is a series of default tags, as indicated in [Add a selection of default tags to all metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62655/209901). This includes [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), [comments](/questions/tagged/comments), bla bla.

Also, there is a series of tags that can just be used by moderators and exist by default, no matter if they have been used before, no matter if no other question uses it<sup>1</sup>. The list contains all the `status-*`, together with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and you can access it by typing "status..." in https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/tags.

Also, you should've already seen that two questions use it! Browse through [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

**So there is no need to create `status-*` tags, they are already in place for when we want to use them.**

<sup>1</sup> Normal tags are removed after 6 months if just one question uses it.

Comment: Somehow, when I looked at the pink tags containing the word "status," I didn't see this particular one.  But now I do see it.  I will fix my question now.